# Oracle database 19c unable to log in right after installation

Tags: database, oracle, authentication

I just installed the oracle database 19c in my laptop (running windows 11 OS).

After installation I was prompted to open the localhost:5500 where I am supposed to provide my username and password.

I tried the ones I created during installation, but it is not working.
[image]

I tried again from sqlplus using the same username and password but with no avail.

```
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Could somebody please help me log in?
I have looked into oracle forums and other related stack overflow threads regarding this but everything seems too cryptic and unnecessarily complicated to the point it feels the product isn't really meant for the uninitiated.

Looking for a simple answer as to why the db won't let me log in using the very same creds it prompted me to create during installation.

Comment: It prompted you for a database username and password; or passwords for the SYS and SYSTEM accounts? You should be able to log in to that page as SYS with the password you set (which is case-sensitive). On the command line you can do `sqlplus / as sysdba` if you're in the authorised OS group. Either way, once you have connected as SYS, create a new user to experiment with, don't use SYS routinely. (And no, it isn't really meant to be simple - it's too big and broad to not be complicated.)

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably for logging into Oracle Enterprise Manager console - and you must have entered the password during installation. In cae you have forgot - login as  SYS / AS SYSDBA from OS prompt and try changing the password of SYSMAN and try again.